# Exception:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Bad handshake

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

I have the following java code.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shincy_intrn","shincy_intrn","shincy");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
int result=st.executeUpdate("insert into test(name)values('Swapna')");
if(result>0)
        System.out.println("Inserted");
```

When I execute the code, I got the following exception,

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Bad handshake
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4098)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4030)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:951)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1717)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1276)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2207)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at TestDb.main(TestDb.java:17)
```

I am using eclipse and mysql5.5.38 on linux server

Comment: Can you restart you mysql server and try again?

Comment: Is connection is established with mysql?

Comment: check this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-relnotes-en/news-5-1-20.html

Comment: What is TestDb.java line 17

Comment: I Have restarted my server several times

Comment: TestDb.java is my class name

Comment: The problem is only for my database. if I change my database name, username and password, it will execute correctly

Comment: Which version of the MySQL Connector/J driver are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.19

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directory and files all have the same file/directory ownership.

I had this issue while upgrading gerrit and tried all possibilities and finally found that some of the directories and files under gerrit were owner by root and not the user with which am starting gerrit.

chmod -R user:group *